# How to implement a timer in my java game?

Tags: java, timer, applet

I would like to implement a timer in my java applet game. For example, how to make a dragon in my game to launch fire every 3 seconds? Please help)

Thanks in advance,
Karen.

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in checking [java Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). The sample code was stolen from the link above:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //If still loading, can't animate.
    if (!worker.isDone()) {
        return;
    }

    loopslot++;

    if (loopslot >= nimgs) {
        loopslot = 0;
        off += offset;

        if (off < 0) {
            off = width - maxWidth;
        } else if (off + maxWidth > width) {
            off = 0;
        }
    }

    animator.repaint();

    if (loopslot == nimgs - 1) {
        timer.restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precious info)))

Answer (score -2):

I'm not so sure it's a fantastic idea preparing yourself to write a game while not knowing how to create a timer. Nonetheless, you can create a timer in several ways; using a timertask, threading, or if using a rendering thread add a tick/delta count - that's a few of many ways.

If you're serious about creating your game, consider using a library like [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) or [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), both of which contain some pretty awesome functionality and abstract classes to assist you along the way. Personally I'd recommend libGDX as it's quite active in development, has an amazing large community and also supports 3D graphics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info!))) Actually, I've already written a lot of stuff for my game but I've never created a timer before in java. I've seen it in SDL before and I knew that for my purposes I need to use some kind of timer. Thank you, dear snh, for your precious help)